# Show that a system of differential equation has a limit cycle.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

WTS that the system

$$x'= -x -y +x(3x^2+y^2)\\
y'= x - y +y(3x^2+y^2)$$

has a limit cycle.

I derived the equation

$$r'(t) = -r(t)(-1+2r^2(t)cos^2\theta(t) +r^2)\\
\theta'(t) = 1$$

but I can't draw the phase plane diagram. How can I do this?

Comment: Well, I'd do it this way: 1) show that the origin is the only equilibrium; 2) find an absorbing annulus: two concentric circles at which vector field pointing inside the annulus; 3) use the Poincare-Bendixson to conclude that since there are no equilibria in this annulus, the only possible $\omega$-limit set is the periodic orbit.

Answer (score 0):

You got
$$
r(1-3r^2)\le \dot r\le r(1-r^2)
$$
which should give you bounds on the time evolution of the radius, or at least and first qualitative information on that evolution.